# How to get the link from a RSS Feed?

Tags: php, xml

I am trying to get the post link of a RSS feed. I load all the posts in an array correctly ( I successfully echo the content and other tags) but I have a problem to get the link.

In the feed, the link can be found by two ways

1.

```
<link rel="alternate" type="text/html" href="this is the address I want" title="here goes the title" />
```

and tried `<?php echo $post->link[href]; ?>` but because there are a lot of link tags in a content, it must echo the one that has `rel="alternate"`

2.

```
<feedburner:origLink>this is the address</feedburner:origLink>
```

and tried `<?php echo $post->feedburner:origLink; ?>`

My question is how to get the link ? I prefer the 2nd way because it does not go through the feedburner link.

**Note:** I use two RSS XML structures in the array so what I will use is something like this

`($post->description)?$post->description:$post->content)` as I do for the description/content

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. `rel=alternate`**

```
$links = $post->xpath('link[@rel="alternate" and @type="text/html"]');
$link  = (string) $links[0]['href'];
```

See http://php.net/simplexmlelement.xpath and http://php.net/simplexml.examples-basic (Example #5)

**2. `feedburner:origLink`**

```
$links = $post->xpath('feedburner:origLink');
$link = (string) $links[0];
// or
$link = (string) $post->children('feedburner', TRUE)->origLink;
```

See http://php.net/simplexmlelement.children

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem but I solved it with the follow:

```
$link = $xml->entry[$i]->link[2]->attributes()->href; 
//the feed-blog has 3 type of links
```

where probably `$xml` is `$post` for you.